# XML parse with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, cdata

I have gt a real big XML of around 10MB in size..
That xml contains a lot of HTML tags.. So when i suppose to parse that xml with jquery i am suppose get the output with proper HTML formatting..
But i am getting the plain text as the Output..

Here is my jquery code which is fetching data from XML

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "finaleve.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
    var markup = [];
    $(xml).find("event").each(function () {
        markup.push('<section><section><div class="mainevent" >' + $(this).find("name").text() +': '+$(this).find("tagline").text()+'</div><br><div class="description" >' + $(this).find("description").text() +'</div><br></section>');

        $(this).find("subevent").each(function () {
        markup.push('<section><div class="maineventse">' + $(this).find("namese").text() +': '+$(this).find("taglinese").text()+'</div><br><div class="description1"  >' + $(this).find("descse").text() +'</div><br></section>');

        });
        markup.push('</section>');
    });
        $(".slides").append(markup.join(""));

}

</script>
```

I know the pure text is because of .text()..
But i dont know its remedy..
Can anybody suggest how to fetch the stuff with their HTML tags..???

Comment: Try wrapping the .text() result in another jQuery call to turn it into parsed HTML

Comment: XML is simple containing <br> and <ul> tags only...

Comment: without a sample how would we be expected to replicate problem?

Comment: you're not passing any callback data to your `xmlParser` function